# Simple Python and Flask question -- 404 error

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a program to display some time and temperature numbers on a web page.  I have two html templates, "index.html" and "set.html" in a "templates" directory under the main "furnace" directory.  The index part works as it should when called by flask but the "set" link (to go to a page to enter a new time and date) results in a "404 Not found" error.  I've stripped everything out of the Python program that isn't part of flask and displaying the html, and I still get the error.  At this point, all that's left is about the same as simple examples I've found; I've compared my program to the examples and I just can't see what's going wrong. Can some sharp eyes spot my mistake?

furnace-9x.py

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smbus
from gpiozero import Button
from flask import Flask, render_template
import SDL_DS3231_dev
import lcddriver
import threading

# Using a global here for simplicity in this demo
# Globals are generally bad practice, so you would maintain
# the status of "lcd_counter" in a more elegant way
# (e.g. through a shared module, through classes, etc.)
# A simple global serves the purpose for this demo
# of a flask server running in parallel to another process
# emulating some I/O, printing to the console, etc.
lcd_counter = 0

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print('Index')
    global datetimestr, temperature
    global minutes_24,minutes_30,heatOn
 
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/set")
def setTime():
    print("Set time")

    return render_template('set.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #=== Prelude ===

    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family:arial;
                background-color: rgb(185,179,175);
                            text-align: left;}
            table, tr {text-align: left;
                font-size: 150%;
                border-style: solid;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Furnace</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">{{dtstr}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>30 day:&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{{m30}}</td>
                    <td>{{p30}}%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>24 hour:&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{{m24}}</td>
                    <td>{{p24}}%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Temp:</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;{{temper}}&deg;F&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Heat:&nbsp;{{heat}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <p><a href="set.html">Set time</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

set.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family:arial;
                background-color: rgb(185,179,175);
                            text-align: left;}
            table, tr {text-align: left;
                font-size: 150%;
                border-style: solid;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Enter the date and time:
            <input type="text" name="datetime" size="15" maxlength="19" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a mismatch between the link in index.html (set.html) and your route (/set).

To resolve the issue, you can update line 35 in your index.html like this:

```
<p><a href="set">Set time</a></p>
```

The flask web server matches the route strings exactly, and not the file names of the templates.  Even better, you can use the flask built in function url_for:

```
<p><a href="{{ url_for('setTime') }}">Set time</a></p>
```